# How can i submit an app-update for iOS 9 before the official release of iOS 9?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have trouble understanding the official/wanted way to do this.

In 10 days Apple will most likely release iOS 9. I have installed XCode 7 Beta and made our app iOS 9 ready. The review process of the app store will take a week or so, so i would like to submit our iOS 9 ready version in the next days, so that when users update their devices to iOS 9 (on 9th sept) they can immediately update the app to iOS 9.

I never had the time to update an app before the release of the new version, so this is all new and confusing to me.

What is the proper way to do this ?

**Update:**

I am NOT using any new features, i removed/reworked stuff that was deprecated. We mainly want to release a version that is iOS 9 compliant before/with the release of iOS 9.

Comment: You have to wait until Apple announces that they are ready to accept iOS9 apps built with Xcode 7

Comment: I think Apple doesn't allow to submit apps from beta versions of Xcode.
By the way : are you using specific API elements of iOS 9 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple would be releasing the GM(Golden Master) build of iOS 9, to the developers, before the wider public release. GM builds are typically released on the new iPhone launch day itself, while the public release is scheduled with the new iPhone availability to the public.

For iOS 8, GM build was released on 9th September 2014 and the public release was on [17th September 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_8).

Hence you'd get at-least a week's time to build and submit your app with GM build of iOS9, before it is released to the public.

Comment: So my assumption that iOS 9 will be released along with the new iPhone on the 9th is wrong ?

Comment: Yes. That is only the announcement date. The new iPhones and the new OS  would be released to public at least a week after.

Comment: This "GM" of iOS 9 will be a "final" version of xcode 7 ?

Comment: GM is the final version of iOS which is installed on devices which are scheduled for public release. From developer perspective GM versions can be used for submitting apps to the the appstore.

Comment: @NikkyD iOS 9 GM seed is now available. Public release date is 16th

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Apple's email has arrived. You can now submit your iOS 9 builds through **Xcode 7 GM** !

---

In a few days, Apple will send an email to all registered iOS developers to announce that you can upload your iOS 9 app.
You have to **wait for this email** to submit your app.
Once you get it, just submit your app from Xcode 7 as you would do with Xcode 6.

Comment: Will any xcode 7 beta suffice or will there be a final xcode 7 that i will have to download and then submit with it

Comment: The current Xcode build at the time of that email is the one you will have to send your build through

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to use any iOS 9 specific functions you can use XCODE 7 and a device running iO9 beta to test your app and remove any bug you find. Then open the project in XCODE 6.4 and submit. I have done this with several apps over the last weeks.